# What's wrong about request.getSession().setAttribute()

Tags: jsp

I use to pass data between `*.java` and `*.jsp`, since this is a MVC framework, it will go by the `*.java` first. so i used `request.getSession().setAttribute("test", "01010101010")` to save the value, and then in `*.jsp`, use `request.getSession().getAttribute("test")` to get value.
But it returns a strange string `"682342348"` all the time.

Comment: At first sight, I don't see why this would not work.

Could you show us the JSP fragment where you use the value?

Comment: right now, i found if i use it in <body><%=request.getAttribute("test")%></body>, everything is OK. 
But when i used it in <script>alert(<%=request.getAttribute("test")%>);</script>  it will output strange string....

Comment: Could be a javascript issue - see my other answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a javascript question now, try adding quotes around the value of the `alert` parameter.

Change this:

```
<script>alert(<%=request.getAttribute("test")%>);</script>
```

To this:

```
<script>alert('<%=request.getAttribute("test")%>');</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the value to a string when you get it out of session:

```
String.valueOf(request.getSession().getAttribute("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your java class and your JSP are getting different session objects somehow. You could try comparing the value you get back from `session.getId()` to make sure they're the same.

However, if all you're trying to do is pass objects from java class to JSP, then you may not need to use the session at all. Instead, store the data as a request attribute:

```
request.setAttribute("test", "01010101010")
```

Comment: Yeah, i used this before, but it also return the error data. and when i try to use request.getAttribute("test").toString(), it throw out a exception

Answer (score 0):

`request.getSession()` - this will create a new session if it doesn't exist. You need to use `request.getSession(false)` if you want to make sure that if the session is not there, it won't be created.