# Weird: session variable returns null from a post controller to a jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, session

In my Java Spring application, I have been trying to figure out why this variable keeps returning null when I alert it in jsp page. I have put system console log and it prints the actual value but on retrieving it in the jsp page, it is null.

This is my attempt in the controller

```
String sound = "sound.mp3";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("mp3", sound);
            String mp3 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("mp3");
            System.out.println("this is the sound notification>>>>>> " + mp3); //this returns the actual value
```

on attempting to retrieve the value in a jsp page, it returns null and this is the attempt

```
<script>
function getNotify() {

        <% String mp3 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("mp3"); %>
        var mp3 = "<%= mp3 %>";
        alert(mp3);
 setInterval(getNotify, 20000);

</script>
```

EDITTED: THIS IS THE COMPLETE CONTROLLER

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post-book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView postBook(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response,
                           @RequestParam String message,
                           @RequestParam String noteVal,
                           @CookieValue(required = true) String name,
                           @CookieValue(required = true) String emailaccess,
                           @CookieValue(required = true) String token) {

        String token2 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("token");

        String emailToken = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("emailaccess");

        try {
            // fetch user info
            User user = _userDao.getByToken(token);

            if (user == null) {
                return logout(request, response);
            }
            //}


            Date today = new Date();
            //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
            SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            String date2 = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
            System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date2);

            // create new book object
            Books book = new Books();
            book.setMessage(message);
            book.setUser(user);
            book.setTimestamp(date2);

            // save book in db
            _bookDao.save(book);



            String sound = "postnotificationsound.mp3";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("sound", sound);
            String mp3 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("sound");
            System.out.println("this is the sound notification>>>>>> " + mp3); //this returns the actual value


            System.out.println("this is the sound notification2>>>>>> " + noteVal);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in saving book: ", e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

please kindly assist

Comment: Did you check you're working with the same session? Maybe you get a new one due to some reason (cookie not getting transferred, some code refreshing the session etc.).

Comment: Yes I did...... And that is the code there

Comment: `request.getSession()` creates a new session if it doesn't exist. You can call it `request.getSession(false)` to make sure that no new session is created for any reason.  Moreover you could post more of your code e.g. the whole controller class and the jsp page.

Comment: could you modify my code and post this as an answer

Comment: It is a comment not an answer. Most likely it won't resolve your problem however it will indicate that you don't have an active session while you think you have. If you post all your code, (spring controller plus jsp page) probably I or someone else could help you more.

Comment: where shoulD i use this request.getSession(false)

Comment: change `<% String mp3 = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("mp3"); %>` to `<% String mp3 = (String) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("mp3"); %>`

Comment: I have added the complete controller

Comment: @elefasGR, Will this in anyway relate to Javascript he is using? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1226020/5086633

Comment: At which stage is your controller method called. Probably your JSP is being loaded earlier before the controller runs and your JSP has already been translated

Comment: And the jsp file? Come on, if you want help you have to give out as much info as possible, this is the 3rd time I ask you to post the jsp and the java files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "${}" is used to fetch the session value which has been set by controller. In your case, 
"${mp3}" will do the trick.
Try this out ->

```
<script>
function getNotify() {
    var mp3 = "${mp3}";
    alert(mp3);        
setInterval(getNotify, 20000);
}
</script>
```